# Using modulus operator in for Loop with if statements - Java beginner

Tags: java, modulus

I hope someone can help. My problem is with using the modulus operator in a for loop. My code is as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)

if (i % 2 == 0) {
method1();
}
else {
method2();
}
```

I understand how this loop works in that it iterates between if and else because of the even and odd numbers created by the condition that uses
the modulus operator (i % 2 == 0)

However, I want to create a condition using the modulus operator so that my loop iterates through 4 methods - as in:

```
loop starts{

method1();
method2();
method3();
method4();

loop repeats
}
```

I can't work out how to accomplish this. I would appreciate any help and advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use plain language first, then try to put it in code.

Comment: *create a condition* you need to tell what condition ?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just put the 4 methods one after each other in the for loop and run 1/4 as many iterations of it? Or can you stop after any one of them?

Comment: Every **2nd** number is `% 2 == 0`. So what you do think every **4th** number would be? Do you know what the `%` operator does?

Comment: you need to use mod 4 instead of mod 2. Modding by 4 essentially maps all real numbers to either 0,1,2,3

Comment: Yeah. I think you need something like `switch (i % 4) { case 0: method1(); break; case 1: method2(); break; case 2: method3(); break; case 3: method4(); break; }`. But it's not clear what exactly it is that you find difficult.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I got the light bulb moment I was after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     if(i%4 == 0)
     {
         condition
     }
     else if(i%4 == 1)
     {
         condition
     }
     else if(i%4 == 2)
     {
         condition
     }
     else if(i%4 == 3)
     {
         condition
     }
}
```

Remember to put it on paper if you're confused and loop through your head (as a beginner)

Comment: Thanks so much Sean. I understand now!

Comment: No problem. Hope you keep going with java. It's a fun language(as are many others)

Answer (score 3):

Put `j = i % 4`
And check for  `method1()` j should be equal to `j = 0`, similarly for 
`Method2()  check j = 1`.  And so on.  Put `for` range conditions to  `1` for infinite loop or desired range.

Answer (score 2):

You could be looking to use the `switch` statement. More on that [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).
Basically it takes a variable to switch between cases.
For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

  switch(i%2) {

    case 0: method0();
            break;
    case 1: method1();
            break;

  }

}
```

Here is the out put if method0 printed 0, and method1 printed 1:
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0

You can edit the modulus to whatever number you want, you just have to account for the different possibilities.